# Перенос каналов в tif

Tags: python, opencv, pillow, tif

Есть условно 2 tif изображения.
С 1го нужно взять слой заднего плана.
С 2го нужно взять сделанные в фотошоп каналы, пример ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После объединить и сохранить в 3м файле.
Слой получилось таким образом взять, но и тут проблема потому что он становиться с названием Слой 0 а не *Фон*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image
background_image = Image.open('1.tif')
foreground_image = Image.open('2.tif')
background_r, background_g, background_b = background_image.split()
foreground_r, foreground_g, foreground_b = foreground_image.split()

new_image = Image.merge('RGB', (background_r, background_g, background_b))

new_image.save('3.tif')
```

Заранее благодарен.